# Both CPUs send a write to the same location at the same time, what values are in the L1/L2/DRAM?

Tags: caching, multiprocessing, hardware, multicore, cpu-architecture

Suppose we have two CPUs, each has an L1 cache associated with it. An L2 cache is shared by the two CPUs, and it requests data from DRAM:

`|CPU0|        |CPU1|
|L1Cache0|    |L1Cache1|
     |Shared L2C|
        |DRAM|`

Let's say CPU0 and CPU1 send out a write signal at the same time:

- At timestamp 0, CPU0 sends a wr request - write address A to 0;
- Also at timestamp 0, CPU1 sends a wr request - write address A to 1;
- At timestamp 0, all of the L1/L2 caches are empty, i.e. write req will result in a miss in the cache;
- At timestamp 0, data in address A in DRAM is 100;
- Cache coherency protocol is MOESI.

What will the values be after these two writes complete? In L1, L2 and DRAM? and what are the states in each cache?

Comment: I understand that MOESI is for L1 caches, what is the typical protocol for L2C?

Comment: My answer was: suppose L2 received CPU0 req first, then in the end the result would be: DRAM=100, L2C=0(dirty), L1-CPU0=0(inval), L1-CPU1=1(modified) . Is that correct?

Comment: Professors sometimes google for students that copy-and-paste a question into a help forum looking for an answer.  It's generally fine if you are stuck on a point and ask for help on that point, but not if you just dump the question.

Comment: This is an interview question; I had provided my answer in the comment